# consolidate order status in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an orders table with records as :

```
employee_id, order_id, status
1, o1, DELIVERED
1, o2, DELIVERED
2, o3, SUBMITTED
2, o4, CREATED
3, o5, SUBMITTED
4, o6, CREATED
```

Now I want to create an select query to group all employees and put a single status, if all order status for an employee are `delivered`, I will set the status to completed. If some orders are `delivered` and some are not deleived then set staus as `in progress`. If for an employee if all orders are `submitted` then set status as `awaiting progress`. Finally default case as `awaiting submission`.

In this example my sql query response should be like:

```
1, completed
2, in progress
3, awaiting submission
4, awaiting progress
```

### Explanation:

employee 1 has orders o1 and o2 both in DELIVERED state so final state is COMPLETED.

employee 2 has orders o3 in submitted and o4 in created state so final state is IN PROGRESS as we have different order states.

employee 2 has orders o1 and o2 both in DELEIVED state so final state is COMPLETED.

employee 3 has order o5 which is submitted state, so single submitted state so status is awaiting progrees

employee 4 has order o6 which is created  but still not submitted so status is awaiting submission.
In sql we can use `case` `when` but how to use the case when we have to group several records and decide the response?

Comment: I can't see how the result matches the criteria

Comment: @Strawberry, I will add more explanation for that

Comment: also add your mysql/marqadb version, this looks like row_number and order by set

Comment: Nope. The result still doesn't match the explanation

Comment: @Strawberry, can you please mention the employee number in my example so i can add more details to it

Comment: It doesn't need more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation for this.  Based on you *description*, it would look like:

```
select employee_id,
       (case when sum(status = 'delivered') = count(*)
             then 'completed'
             when sum(status = 'delivered') > 0
             then 'in progress'
             when sum(status = 'submitted') > 0
             then 'awaiting 'progress'
             else 'awaiting submission'
        end) as status
from t
group by employee_id
```